# Possible to pass parameters via Looker Studio Linking API?

Tags: looker-studio

Question for anyone using the Looker Studio Linking API: Can I pass a parameter value via the Linking API URL so it gets used in the created copy of the report?

The Linking API has its own parameter types that can be included in the URL in order to accomplish various things (URL parameters, Control parameters, Report parameters) but I'm talking about finding a way to set the value of a parameter that is part of a report's embedded data source.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can pass parameter values in the URL.

There is no description of this in the [Linking API documentation](https://developers.google.com/looker-studio/integrate/linking-api), which seems to be an oversight since it is possible. A description of how can be found in the [Overridable config parameters](https://developers.google.com/looker-studio/connector/data-source-parameters#set_url_parameters) section of the Developer's Guide for Community Connectors.

In summary, you need to:

1. Switch the report to Edit mode
2. Go to "Resource" -> "Manage report URL parameters" in the menu and check the "Allow to be modified in report URL" check box for the parameter you want to pass. Also take note of the parameter name, in the example it's `ds0.zipcode`

   [image: Configuration of report URL parameters]
3. Create a JSON string with the parameter name and value:

   ```json
   {
     "ds0.zipcode": "94094"
   }
   ```
4. URL-encode the JSON string you created:

   ```
   %7B%22ds0.zipcode%22%3A%2294094%22%7D
   ```
5. Add a query parameter named `params` to the report URL with the above URL-encoded JSON as the value:

   ```
   https://lookerstudio.google.com/reporting/REPORT_ID/page/PAGE_ID?params=%7B%22ds0.zipcode%22%3A%2294094%22%7D
   ```

   *(Replace `REPORT_ID` and `PAGE_ID` with the values for your report)*

Note that there is a limitation when using the same parameter for multiple data sources in a report. The parameter will show up with a different name for each data source in the "Manage report URL parameters" page, and you will need to add the same value for each one in the URL (see [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/180705297) in Google's bug tracker)

Comment: Wow, thank you SO much! This seemed like it should be possible but I just wasn't sure how to combine the two things. I will dig into your suggestions more. Again, thank you! And happy holidays.